# Checking checkboxes using javascript when there id's have a certain character within

Tags: javascript, html

I need to check a certain selection of checkboxes using JavaScript. All these checkboxes have the letter a at the beginning of the id and other checkboxes have a different letter.I also don't know how many of these checkboxes there will be since they are created dynamically

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a1" />
```

Now if I click on a button a JavaScript function is called and these checkboxes with letter a at beginning of id's should be checked, is this possible and how?

Is there something that can be used in conjunction with `document.getElementById('a').checked`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the checkboxes and loop through them, like this:

```
var checks = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0, cb; cb = checks[i]; i++) {
   if(cb.type.toLowerCase() == 'checkbox' && cb.id && cb.id.charAt(0) == 'a')
     cb.checked = true;
}
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/YPu69/1/)

*Edit:* a bit cleaner to use [`.charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/charAt), good call and thanks [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down)!

Comment: +1. `cb.id.substring(0, 1)` might be better as `cb.id.charAt(0)`.

Comment: @Tim - Good call, I so rarely use it it's always forgotten, but definitely cleaner for this.  Updated to use `.charAt()` instead :)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to specify a class 'a' to the inputs with id ="a*' and then select all the checkboxes with that specific class using jQuery

example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a1" class="a" />
```

code in jQuery:

```
$(".myClass").attr('checked', true);
```

I hope this helps and if you don't mind using jQuery

Comment: You could also do `$("input:checkbox[id^=a]").attr('checked', true);` without changing markup...but including jQuery is overkill for this :)  By that I mean it's overkill including it for *just* this.

Answer (score 0):

Newer browsers (IE8, Firefox, Chrome, Opera) have [*querySelectorAll()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll) which will allow you to do something like this:

```
var chks = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox][id^=a]");
```

This would find all elements with *type="checkbox"* and an *id* attribute that starts with the letter a.  For older browsers, you'd have to use something like [Nick Craver's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414143/checking-checkboxes-using-javascript-when-there-ids-have-a-certain-character-wit/3414175#3414175).  Alternatively, you could use something like [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), which is the CSS selector engine used in jQuery.